# Is it possible/advisable to run Spring Boot without controllers just for the @ScheduledTasks and ORM?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to run a Spring Boot service without any of the controller-related stuff. I'd like it to just run a scheduled task every hour and do work if needed. I'm wanting to use Spring Boot, because I already know how to set the Hibernate ORM up, and I'm re-using a lot of the same repositories as another Spring Boot service. So, I spun up a new Spring Boot project and left out the start-web package.

The main issue I'm running into is that despite having a scheduled task set up, the service starts and immediately quits without running the scheduled task. In my head, I imagined the service kind of just sitting there, running, waiting for the time to trigger the scheduled job I have configured and kind of just sleeping until then. Are my expectations bad, or do I just have it misconfigured?

Comment: Add the code snippet of your @ScheduledTask. It should be possible I guess

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Read about scheduled tasks in Spring from these links.

`https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks`

`https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/`

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding the problem. I know how scheduled tasks work. I've made them work in other Spring apps that happened to also have Controller-related stuff in them. 

What happens is that without Controller-related stuff, the service doesn't stay running long enough for the task to run. It starts up, and then immediately shuts down, since it's not in any kind of "listening for requests" mode.

Comment: It should be possible. Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem. It was a configuration issue causing the Spring Boot app to not recognize the presence of required configuration values in the application.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Use @EnableScheduling in main class and application won't shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove `spring-boot-starter-web` from your dependencies or in your main class you can configure the `SpringApplicationBuilder` to not include the web server.

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApplication.class)
  .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
  .run(args);
```

Comment: Yes. And then the app starts up and immediately shuts down before even trying to run any scheduled tasks.